# Compute Carmichael function and Euler’s totient function

Tags: number-theory

How can I compute the Carmichael function and Euler’s totient function of 172872 ?

Thank you

Comment: As $$172872=2^33^27^4,$$ use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html

Answer (score 1):

You use the formulas: for [Carmichael function](http://oeis.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) and for Euler's function (which is the same as for Carmichael, but you use just a product instead of the LCM. You need to factor your number first, but for this number factoring is easy.

Comment: One further difference is that $\phi(2^n)=2^{n-1}$ whereas $\lambda(2^n)=2^{n-2}$ for $n>2$.